# Update Manager doesn't work + Sotware Center crashes

Tags: software-installation, appcenter

Yesterday when updating my OS, the Update manager freezed and wasn't responding. I waited but finally force the exit and shut it down. Now it shows up a message saying something like: "Updates cannot be installed. Proceed with a parcial update or write sudo apt-get install -f in terminal". I try both but it ain't working.

Also, today trying to install software from the Software Center, it also freezes and crashes. What can I do to bring everything back up again?

Thanks! :)